# TypeError: () takes no arguments Ошибка

Tags: python

Я писал небольшую игру и возникла ошибка коде:

```
    clouds = Clouds(MAP_W, MAP_H)
TypeError: Clouds() takes no arguments
```

Не понимаю из-за чего появляется ошибка, если кто-то знает, помогите пожалуйста.

Вот код:

```py
from pynput import keyboard
from cloud import Clouds
import time
import os
from map import Map
from helicopter import Helicopter as Helico

TICK_SLEEP = 0.1
CLOUDS_UPDATE = 20
TREE_UPDATE = 50
FIRE_UPDATE = 25
MAP_W, MAP_H = 20, 10

helico = Helico(MAP_W, MAP_H)
tmp = Map(MAP_W, MAP_H)
clouds = Clouds(MAP_W, MAP_H)
MOVES = {'w': (-1, 0), 'd': (0, 1), 's': (1, 0), 'a': (0, -1)}


def process_key(key):
    global helico
    c = key.char.lower()
    if c in MOVES.keys():
        dx, dy = MOVES[c][0], MOVES[c][1]
        helico.move(dx, dy)


listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=None, on_release=process_key)
listener.start()

if tmp.check_bounds(20, 30):
    print('YES')
tmp.generate_forest(3, 10)
tmp.generate_rivers(10)
tmp.generate_rivers(10)
tmp.generate_rivers(10)
tmp.generate_upgrade_shop()
tmp.generate_hospital()

tick = 1

while True:
    os.system('cls')
    tmp.process_helicopter(helico, clouds)
    helico.print_stats()
    tmp.print_map(helico, clouds)
    print('TICK', tick)
    tick +=1

    time.sleep(TICK_SLEEP)
    if tick % TREE_UPDATE == 0:
        tmp.add_tree()
    if tick % FIRE_UPDATE == 0:
        tmp.add_fire()
    if tick % CLOUDS_UPDATE == 0:
        clouds.update()
```

Comment: `Clouds() не принимает аргументов` - перевод ошибки.

Comment: Значит в `__init__` вашего класса `Clouds` нет параметров кроме self, а вы туда два параметра пытаетесь передать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строчке `clouds = Clouds(MAP_W, MAP_H)` вы создаёте объект класса `Clouds`, передавая ему аргументы `MAP_W` и `MAP_H`. Ошибка возникает, потому что в методе `__init__(self)` класса `Clouds`, который описан в файле `cloud.py` нет аргументов, кроме `self`. Чтобы исправить эту ошибку, вам нужно добавить аргументы в конструктор класса `Clouds`. Это может выглядеть так:

```
class Clouds:
    def __init__(self, map_width, map_height): # изменяем конструктор класса
        ... # ваш код здесь
```

Comment: у меня уже прописаны эти аргументы в __init__

Comment: @Wizurd можете, пожалуйста, привести код из файла `clouds.py`? вполне возможно, вы случайно написали `init` вместо `__init__`

Comment: `from utils import randbool

class Clouds:
    def __int__(self, w, h):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.cells = [[0 for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]

    def update(self, r = 1, mxr = 10, g = 1, mxg = 10):
        for i in range(self.h):
            for j in range(self.w):
                if randbool(r, mxr):
                    self.cells[i][j] = 1
                    if randbool(g,mxg):
                        self.cells[i][j] = 2
                else:
                    self.cells[i][j] = 0`

Comment: @Wizurd вы написали `__int__`, вместо `__init__`, опечатка вышла :-) Если вы её исправите, всё должно работать